# Error en condicion if PHP

Tags: php, condiciones

Estoy haciendo una condicion que si el campo $location1 esta completo, ejecute una funcion y si el campo $location2 esta completo ejecute una funcion similar en el mismo campo.
no puede encontrar el error en la condición, podran ayudarme?
Gracias!

```
    add_filter ('bps_hidden_filters', 'directory_filters');
    function directory_filters ($filters)
    {
        $user = bp_loggedin_user_id ();
        if (empty ($user))  return $filters;

        $filters['bps_directory'] = bps_current_page ();

    $location1 = xprofile_get_field_data (46, $user ); 
    $location2 = xprofile_get_field_data (52, $user ); 


   if (!empty ($location1)){
$filters['field_62'] = empty ($_REQUEST['field_62'])? addslashes ($location1): $_REQUEST['field_62'];} else  {
 $filters['field_62'] = empty ($_REQUEST['field_62'])? addslashes ($location2): $_REQUEST['field_62'];}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero puedes probar colocar un var_dump para ver si la variable $location1 devuelve algún valor: `var_dump($location1)`.
Si devuelve valor, el error estará en el condicional. Puedes despejar dudas creando un `if($location1 != '')`{....}.
*Si las 2 variables tienen valores, el resultado en principio, tal y como lo tienes mostrará sólo el de $location1. Si quieres enseñar los 2 valores deberás hacer 2 condicionales normales en lugar del else if().

Comment: Hola Marcel, cuando $location1 tiene un valor, $location2 esta vacio y viceversa. Probe con var_dumpl y arroja el resultado. Esta mal el método utilizado de if? Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Qué valor devuelve? Por lógica, si el var_dump devuelve NULL, el empty debería de funcionar, aunque podrías utilizar también `if (isset($location1)) `{... En el caso que el empty no funcione, es porque la variable trae algo distinto a un valor vacío.

Comment: `if (isset($location1)){
 $filters['field_62'] = empty ($_REQUEST['field_62'])? addslashes ($location1): $_REQUEST['field_62'];
 return $filters;
}} `
funciona, pero cuando le agrego la segunda condicion no arroja correctamente los resultados. El var dump cuando esta vacio arroja " "

Comment: Vale, es un avance. La segunda condición la tienes separada verdad? Me refiero a que son 2 if(). Uno para `$location1` y otro para `$location2` ? Si no es así, intenta separarlas porque si el primero funciona el segundo debería de funcionar también.

Comment: Muchas Gracias! funciono asi. con dos condiciones y con !empty

Comment: Genial! Hasta la próxima! :)